# Find the closest locations using Angular and firebase Database

Tags: angular, firebase, google-maps-api-3

I am in conception phase and I need your advises :

I am using Angular 5 for my front end website, I have a search page where user can fill his address (using google maps autocomplete api or current location) and make a search, the application should display the nearest ads (radius 1km).

Each ad has lat and long.
Iam using Firebase backend, my question is : is there any optimize way to do search ? should i do the distance calculation on the front or Back ?

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

GeoFire for JavaScript is most probably the library you need:

> [It] allows you to store and query a set of keys based on their geographic
>   location... GeoFire selectively loads only the data near certain
>   locations, keeping your applications light and responsive, even with
>   extremely large datasets.

See the dedicated page: https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/geofire-js/